# While loop doesn't exit or display results

Tags: java, loops, methods

Homework assignment: I've been asked to create a method that will count all the odd numbers from 1 to value assigned to variable but it has to be with a while loop.

I've been using modulus to try and determine whether or not it's even or odd. I've tried identifying odd numbers and then just using + 2. I suspect it's a simple logic error I don't quite see.

```
public static void sumOddNumber(int number){

    int counter =1;

    while (counter <= number){
        if (counter % 2 !=0){
            System.out.println (+ number);
            counter++;
        }
    }

}
```

My expectation was for it to compare counter to number(the user defined variable) and to keep performing the modulus operation and printing the result, until counter exceeds number. However when I enter a number it just prints that number and keeps grinding away.

Comment: Try dropping the + inside System.out.println

Comment: *until counter exceeds number* counter will not exceed the number if you have `counter++` inside the `if` block.

Comment: Thanks for the quick comment. I entered the number 25 and the terminal just display 25 and kept spinning away.

Comment: By taking my counter out of my if statement it now terminates and does mostly what I want. I enter the number 12 and it spits out 12 6 times. I enter 3 and it return 3 twice. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed with @forpas, your `counter++` is only called once.

Try this...

```
public static void printOddNumber(int number){

    int counter = 1;

    while (counter <= number) {

        if (counter % 2 !=0) {

            System.out.println(counter);
        }
        counter++;
    }
}
```

A somewhat better answer from a readability standpoint...

```
public static void printOddNumber(int number){

    int counter = 1;

    while (counter <= number) {

        if (isOddNumber(counter)) {

            System.out.println(counter);
        }
        counter++;
    }
}

public static boolean isOddNumber(int number) {

    return number % 2 != 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Once I removed the counter++ statement outside of the loop, I started receiving the correct number of iterations but all showing the number that I had input. I just had to change my System.out.println to display the correct variable, in this case 'counter' not 'number' like I had. My method ended up looking like the first example hooknc put up. Thanks to everyone for all the help.